# Failed to compile with "-DLLVM_DISTRIBUTION_COMPONENTS="cxx;cxxabi;cxx-headers"

Tags: cmake, compilation, llvm

When trying to build cxx (LLVM 16), I got tons of errors saying missing headers and missing libraries.

The build command was

```
cmake -G Ninja /workspace/llvm-project/llvm \
      -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES="libcxx;libcxxabi" \
      -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86" \
      -DLLVM_DISTRIBUTION_COMPONENTS="cxx;cxxabi" \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/vscode/libcxx \
      -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=`which clang` \
      -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=`which clang++`
```

The error messages look like...

```
CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: 'malloc/malloc.h' file not found
CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: 'valgrind/valgrind.h' file not found

FAILED: cmTC_eec8f 
: && /usr/local/bin/clang -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pfm_initialize -O3 -DNDEBUG   CMakeFiles/cmTC_eec8f.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_eec8f  -lpfm  -lm && :
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpfm
clang-16: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I change the build command to

```
cmake -G Ninja /workspace/llvm-project/llvm \
      -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES="libcxx;libcxxabi" \
      -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86" \
      -DLLVM_DISTRIBUTION_COMPONENTS="runtimes" \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/vscode/libcxx_symcc \
      -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=`which clang` \
      -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=`which clang++`
```

The errors will be delayed to `cmake --build .` instead of config phase. And the errors would look like...

```
[0/3] Performing build step for 'runtimes'
[1/129] Building CXX object libcxxabi/src/CMakeFiles/cxxabi_static_objects.dir/stdlib_exception.cpp.o
FAILED: libcxxabi/src/CMakeFiles/cxxabi_static_objects.dir/stdlib_exception.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/c++  -DHAVE___CXA_THREAD_ATEXIT_IMPL -DLIBCXX_BUILDING_LIBCXXABI -D_LIBCPP_BUILDING_LIBRARY -D_LIBCXXABI_BUILDING_LIBRARY -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I/workspace/llvm-project/libcxxabi/../libcxx/src -I/workspace/symcc/libcxx_symcc/include/c++/v1 -I/workspace/symcc/libcxx_symcc/include/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/c++/v1 -I/workspace/llvm-project/libcxxabi/include -fno-semantic-interposition -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Werror=date-time -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-class-memaccess -Wno-redundant-move -Wno-pessimizing-move -Wno-noexcept-type -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wsuggest-override -Wno-comment -Wno-misleading-indentation -fdiagnostics-color -fdata-sections  -O3 -DNDEBUG   -nostdinc++ -Werror=return-type -W -Wall -Wchar-subscripts -Wconversion -Wmissing-braces -Wunused-function -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wsign-conversion -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wstrict-overflow=4 -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wno-suggest-override -Wno-error -pedantic -fstrict-aliasing -D_DEBUG -UNDEBUG -std=c++2a -MD -MT libcxxabi/src/CMakeFiles/cxxabi_static_objects.dir/stdlib_exception.cpp.o -MF libcxxabi/src/CMakeFiles/cxxabi_static_objects.dir/stdlib_exception.cpp.o.d -o libcxxabi/src/CMakeFiles/cxxabi_static_objects.dir/stdlib_exception.cpp.o -c /workspace/llvm-project/libcxxabi/src/stdlib_exception.cpp
In file included from /workspace/symcc/libcxx_symcc/include/c++/v1/type_traits:510,
                 from /workspace/symcc/libcxx_symcc/include/c++/v1/exception:381,
                 from /workspace/symcc/libcxx_symcc/include/c++/v1/new:97,
                 from /workspace/llvm-project/libcxxabi/src/stdlib_exception.cpp:9:
/workspace/symcc/libcxx_symcc/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_trivially_destructible.h:34:2: error: #error is_trivially_destructible is not implemented
   34 | #error is_trivially_destructible is not implemented
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /workspace/symcc/libcxx_symcc/include/c++/v1/new:93,
                 from /workspace/llvm-project/libcxxabi/src/stdlib_exception.cpp:9:
/workspace/symcc/libcxx_symcc/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_same.h:22:53: error: there are no arguments to ‘__is_same’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘__is_same’ must be available [-fpermissive]
   22 | struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_same : _BoolConstant<__is_same(_Tp, _Up)> { };
      |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~
/workspace/symcc/libcxx_symcc/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_same.h:22:53: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
/workspace/symcc/libcxx_symcc/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_same.h:22:72: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   22 | struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_same : _BoolConstant<__is_same(_Tp, _Up)> { };
      |                                                                        ^
```

I've been stuck for a while. Any help is really appreciated.